# How to encode search text

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, com-search

I'm having a bit of a situation here, because of encoding. This problem occurs only on internet explorer (yes, that guy ...).

I'm using the search component, which works nice by the way, but whenever I try to search something with, let's say, an accent, everything goes wrong on IE, because that character doesn't get encoded.

For an example, I'm searching "crédit", so the URL that gets generated is :

`http://mywebsite.com/index.php/search-result?searchword=crédit&searchphrase=all`

I'd like to have the encoded version, which should be :

`http://mywebsite.com/index.php/search-result?searchword=cr%C3%A9dit&searchphrase=all`

However, I can't manage to find where I could change that. Of course, I want to do it as good as possible, which means not modifying any of the Joomla core file, or base components/modules/plugins.

Long story short, I sighted an event which could help me : onSearch, however I can't find any example of it and can't get it working.

PS : Joomla 3.5 here.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: IE 11, I'm not the kind of guy trying to get anything to work below that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the file `/modules/mod_search/tmpl/default.php` to `templates/joomla-template/html/mod_search` (make sure that the file doesn't exist under the destination directory first)

Add the following to the `form` tag:

```
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

So, your form tag should be something like:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did just that but on the `com_search/tmpl/default_form.php` Works like a charm ! Thanks, didn't know this trick ! :)

Comment: For me it did not work in Edge, but it does in IE =< IE11. Although in Joomla 1.7 search did work correctly without adding this `enctype`